# How can I use a POP3 email account on a Windows RT device?

Tags: email, pop3, windows-rt

I struggled to find the answer to this after much googling and a month of searching.

When googling all I could find was information telling me that Windows RT's native mail app does not support POP3 emails and I would have to create a sort of proxy account where I would send emails with something like `1684368467@hotmail.com via mychosenemail@mybrandedserver.com` in the from field. I consider this to be a detrimental compromise.

I then tried to see if there were any other mail clients available for Windows RT but a number of searches did not produce any results.

When I'd almost given up I finally found the answer that should have been easy to find yet wasn't.

I'm not usually one to ask and then answer my own question but I was considering asking this here while I was trying to find a solution. I think it also has great SEO potential.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found `Outlook 2013` hidden away amongst the apps. As far as I'm aware, its the only way to get POP3 email on a Windows RT device.

I set it up in exactly the same way I would on a normal computer, there are many tutorials available on how to do that.

I'm not sure if you have to pay for it as it wasn't my device.

The most important point I'm making is that you can get POP3 email on Windows RT through Outlook 2013, despite the lack of results on search engines. Hopefully this will help many people. :)